# PayPal METHOD = DoDirectPayment #10759 error

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am using Paypal transaction by DoDirectPayment method, I have verified my API credentials about 100 times; it's not wrong.

```
 Array (
        [TIMESTAMP] => 0000-00-00T00:00:00Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 0000000000
        [ACK] => Failure
        [VERSION] => 56.0
        [BUILD] => 000000
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10759
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction cannot be processed.
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Please use a different payment card.
        [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        [AMT] => 0.50
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

Above is response what I am getting from paypal.

I am tried all cards from here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

My Code:

```
$request  = 'METHOD=DoDirectPayment';
$request .= '&VERSION=56.0';
$request .= '&USER='.$paypal_user;
$request .= '&PWD='.$paypal_pass;
$request .= '&SIGNATURE='.$paypal_sign;
$request .= '&CUSTREF=' . $post_id;
$request .= '&PAYMENTACTION=Authorization';
$request .= '&AMT='.$amount;
$request .= '&EXPDATE=' . $expmonth . $expyear;
$request .= '&CVV2=' . $ccv;
$request .= '&ACCT=' . $card_number;
$request .= '&CURRENCYCODE=USD';
$request .= '&IPADDRESS=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$request .= '&CREDITCARDTYPE=' . $cardtype; // VISA AND ALL

$curl = curl_init($apiurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

// Request to paypal
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you sending the test card data to _sandbox_ (vs. production) [endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#wpp)? The error points to Paypal _declining_ the card which would be expected if sending _test_ cards to production....

Comment: I don't understand your point? I am using sandbox account for test payment and I am getting this error while testing transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cards provided at that URL have been used so much in the sandbox that they simply don't work anymore.  With PayFlow they do, but not with DoDirectPayment.

Instead, [generate fresh numbers here](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/) when you need them.  Any number generated there will work with any security code and valid expiration date.

Comment: Yes, above card details works for me. but, why shouldn't I use standard card details provided by PayPal? Is there any things wrong with code?

Comment: Those numbers are just overused and the system doesn't like them anymore.  If your code is working with the freshly generated numbers then your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Angell My code is working with freshly generated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may try create new dummy card info in step 4 within below page and try your test again.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1413